# Div table not showing on mobile site

Tags: css, list, html, mobile

I'm hoping someone here can assist me.  I've created a table for my site using  tags, since the 'old school' way of creating it with `<table>` does not work on a mobile site - everything is cut off along the right hand side, without the option to slide it over.

My code is:

```
<style>
.list_item1 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 200px;
}
.list_item2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
    width: 600px;
}
#wraplist {
    width:800px;
    column-count:2;
    column-gap:10px;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -moz-column-gap:20px;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-gap:20px;
}

</style>
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div id="wraplist">
<div class="list_item1"><li>A</li></div>
<div class="list_item1"><li>B</li></div>
<div class="list_item1"><li>C</li></div>
<div class="list_item1"><li>D</li></div>
<div class="list_item1"><li>E</li></div>
<div class="list_item2"><li>F</li></div>
<div class="list_item2"><li>G</li></div>
<div class="list_item2"><li>H</li></div>
<div class="list_item2"><li>I</li></div>
<div class="list_item2"><li>J</li></div>
</div>
<div style='clear:both;'>&nbsp;</div>
```

In case you're wondering why I'm using a Div instead of a `<ul>` controlled through the CSS, it's because for whatever reason, it doesn't work.  I've literally copied and pasted other code that was proven to work, within my site and it simply shows as one list instead of a list divided into two columns.  The div creates two lists but they don't show on a mobile site.  The outcome is that "list_item1" shows, then one line - the first one, from "list_item2" shows with a very large font, and everything else has vanished.

I've created two 'list items' due to the fact that I need the column to be larger to make room for the extra text in the second row.  I can't have them equal in size.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to fix this so that it displays on a mobile device? Or an alternative method that does?

Comment: That structure will not validate, `li` MUST be within `ul`

Comment: Ok, I'm getting closer.  I added: @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) { and removed padding for the code that applies to the mobile browser.  Now my issue is the fact that the wording doesn't always line up to the bullet...I applied 'list-style-position: inside;' but it didn't work.

Comment: Oh sorry, just saw your comment Paulie_D.  Thanks for responding! I'll remove the li to see if that lines it up properly.